# Chart.js Stacked Group Bar model after updating version Chart.js 2.9.4 -> Chart.js 3.5.0

Tags: primefaces, chart.js, xhtml

I use Primefaces together with Chart.js in the last update they migrated from **Chart.js 2.9.4** to **Chart.js 3.5.0**

And with that, the graphic model that I used was not configured, see the 2 small videos of the before and after.

See how my chart was and after update it bug

Before
https://www.loom.com/share/ca3919221a154f0d9cf9bbe41843cf2b

After
https://www.loom.com/share/e9c0ac3e7df942a7aac74a19deb49c6a

If you prefer, here in the Primefaces forum I opened a call, and in it I show an example of the code.

https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=72619

```
    public void criarGraficoFluxoCaixaMensal() {
            barContasReceberPagarAnual = new BarChartModel();
            ChartData data = new ChartData();
    
            LineChartDataSet dataBalancoPrevisto = new LineChartDataSet();
            List<Object> balancoPrevisto = new ArrayList<Object>();
            LineChartDataSet dataBalancoRealizado = new LineChartDataSet();
            List<Object> balancoRealizado = new ArrayList<Object>();
    
            BarChartDataSet barDataReceitaPrevista = new BarChartDataSet();
            barDataReceitaPrevista.setLabel("Recebimentos previstos");
            barDataReceitaPrevista.setBackgroundColor("rgba(102, 187, 106, 0.3)");
            barDataReceitaPrevista.setBorderColor("rgb(102, 187, 106)");
            barDataReceitaPrevista.setStack("principal");
            List<Number> listaContasReceberPrevisto = new ArrayList<Number>();
            List<Object[]> resultReceita = dao.buscarTotalContasReceberAnualPrevisto();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
             listaContasReceberPrevisto.add(0.0);
                balancoPrevisto.add(0.0);
                balancoRealizado.add(0.0);
    
            }
            for (Object[] result : resultReceita) {
                listaContasReceberPrevisto.add(((int) result[0] - 1), (Number) result[1]);
    
            }
            barDataReceitaPrevista.setData(listaContasReceberPrevisto);
    
            BarChartDataSet barDataDespesaPrevista = new BarChartDataSet();
            barDataDespesaPrevista.setLabel("Pagamentos previstos");
            barDataDespesaPrevista.setBackgroundColor("rgba(239, 83, 80, 0.3)");
            barDataDespesaPrevista.setBorderColor("rgb(239, 83, 80)");
            barDataDespesaPrevista.setStack("principal");
            List<Number> listaContasPagarPrevisto = new ArrayList<Number>();
            List<Object[]> resultsDespesa = dao.buscarTotalContasPagarAnualPrevisto();
    
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                listaContasPagarPrevisto.add(0.0);
    
            }
            Number in;
            for (Object[] result : resultsDespesa) {
                in = (Number) result[1];
                listaContasPagarPrevisto.add(((int) result[0] - 1), -in.intValue());
    
            }
            barDataDespesaPrevista.setData(listaContasPagarPrevisto);
    
            BarChartDataSet barDataDespesaRealizada = new BarChartDataSet();
            barDataDespesaRealizada.setLabel("Pagamentos realizados");
            barDataDespesaRealizada.setBackgroundColor("rgba(239, 83, 80, 0.6)");
            barDataDespesaRealizada.setBorderColor("rgb(239, 83, 80)");
            barDataDespesaRealizada.setStack("principal");
            List<Number> listaContasPagarRealizada = new ArrayList<Number>();
            List<Object[]> resultsDespesaRealizada = dao.buscarTotalContasPagarAnual();
    
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                listaContasPagarRealizada.add(0.0);
    
            }
            for (Object[] result : resultsDespesaRealizada) {
                in = (Number) result[1];
                listaContasPagarRealizada.add(((int) result[0] - 1), -in.intValue());
    
            }
            barDataDespesaRealizada.setData(listaContasPagarRealizada);
    
            BarChartDataSet barDataReceitaRealizada = new BarChartDataSet();
            barDataReceitaRealizada.setLabel("Recebimentos realizados");
            barDataReceitaRealizada.setBackgroundColor("rgba(102, 187, 106, 0.6)");
            barDataReceitaRealizada.setBorderColor("rgb(102, 187, 106)");
            barDataReceitaRealizada.setStack("principal");
            List<Number> listaContasReceberRealizada = new ArrayList<Number>();
            List<Object[]> resultsReceberRealizada = dao.buscarTotalContasReceberAnual();
    
            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                listaContasReceberRealizada.add(0.0);
    
            }
            for (Object[] result : resultsReceberRealizada) {
                listaContasReceberRealizada.add(((int) result[0] - 1), (Number) result[1]);
    
            }
            barDataReceitaRealizada.setData(listaContasReceberRealizada);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                try {
                    balancoPrevisto.add(i, listaContasReceberPrevisto.get(i).intValue() - (Math.abs(listaContasPagarPrevisto.get(i).intValue())));
    
                    balancoRealizado.add(i, (listaContasReceberRealizada.get(i).intValue() - (Math.abs(listaContasPagarRealizada.get(i).intValue()))));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    balancoPrevisto.add(i, 0);
                    balancoRealizado.add(i, 0);
                }
    
            }
            dataBalancoPrevisto.setData(balancoPrevisto);
            dataBalancoPrevisto.setFill(false);
            dataBalancoPrevisto.setLabel("Saldo previsto");
            dataBalancoPrevisto.setBackgroundColor("rgba(66, 165, 245, 0.3)");
            dataBalancoPrevisto.setBorderColor("rgba(66, 165, 245, 0.3)");
            dataBalancoPrevisto.setTension(0.1);
            dataBalancoRealizado.setData(balancoRealizado);
            dataBalancoRealizado.setFill(false);
            dataBalancoRealizado.setLabel("Saldo realizado");
            dataBalancoRealizado.setBackgroundColor("rgba(66, 165, 245, 0.6)");
            dataBalancoRealizado.setBorderColor("rgb(66, 165, 245)");
            dataBalancoRealizado.setTension(0.1);
            data.addChartDataSet(dataBalancoPrevisto);
            data.addChartDataSet(dataBalancoRealizado);
            data.addChartDataSet(barDataDespesaPrevista);
            data.addChartDataSet(barDataDespesaRealizada);
            data.addChartDataSet(barDataReceitaPrevista);
            data.addChartDataSet(barDataReceitaRealizada);
    
            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
            labels.add("Janeiro");
            labels.add("Fevereiro");
            labels.add("Março");
            labels.add("Abril");
            labels.add("Maio");
            labels.add("Junho");
            labels.add("Julho");
            labels.add("Agosto");
            labels.add("Setembro");
            labels.add("Outubro");
            labels.add("Novembro");
            labels.add("Dezembro");
            data.setLabels(labels);
            barContasReceberPagarAnual.setData(data);
    
            //Options
            /*BarChartOptions options = new BarChartOptions();
            CartesianScales cScales = new CartesianScales();
            CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
            linearAxes.setStacked(true);
    
            cScales.addXAxesData(linearAxes);
            cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
            options.setScales(cScales);
    
            Title title = new Title();
            title.setDisplay(true);
            title.setText("Bar Chart - Stacked");
            options.setTitle(title);
    
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            tooltip.setMode("index");
            tooltip.setIntersect(false);
            options.setTooltip(tooltip);*/
            BarChartOptions options = new BarChartOptions();
            CartesianScales cScales = new CartesianScales();
            CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
            CartesianLinearTicks ticks = new CartesianLinearTicks();
            ticks.setBeginAtZero(true);
            linearAxes.setTicks(ticks);
    
            cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
            options.setScales(cScales);
    
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            tooltip.setMode("index");
            tooltip.setDisplayColors(true);
            tooltip.setIntersect(true);
            barContasReceberPagarAnual.setOptions(options);
            barContasReceberPagarAnual.setExtender("currencyBr");
        }
```

The light green is the predicted one and the dark green is the accomplished one, as the forecast bar is being executed, it is hidden by the accomplished one.

[image]

See that now what has been accomplished is not overlapping with what was expected.

[image]

I tried to test according to your code, but the problem persists.

The problem is in the union of 4 bars starting at the same place, we want to put the 4 bars in a single Stacked.

See that if I change these two lines the bars are side by side

```
 barDataReceitaPrevista.setStack("principal");
 barDataDespesaPrevista.setStack("principal");
 barDataReceitaRealizada.setStack("principal_1");
 barDataDespesaRealizada.setStack("principal_1");
```

[image]

And when I try to make them start in the same place, it looks like this

```
 barDataReceitaPrevista.setStack("principal");
 barDataDespesaPrevista.setStack("principal");
 barDataReceitaRealizada.setStack("principal");
 barDataDespesaRealizada.setStack("principal");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK so the problem is you are setting both your axes to `stacked:true` which will force ChartsJS to "add" the values together. to get them to "overlap" you need to set Y Axes to `stacked:false` like this..

```java
CartesianLinearAxes xAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
xAxes.setStacked(true);
cScales.addXAxesData(xAxes);

CartesianLinearAxes yAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
yAxes.setStacked(false);
cScales.addYAxesData(yAxes);
```